Does Daniel 9 prove that the messiah would come in the 2nd temple period?
I reading the Tankah and a Christian friend of mine was debating on Daniel 9, he is an evangelical pastor and he told me that Daniel 9 proves to us that the messiah would come in the second temple period and that only Christ himself could fulfil that,does Daniel 9 prove that the messiah would come in the 2nd temple period?

Th Book of Daniel was written in the second century BCE, so technically it WAS the Second-Temple period.

There are also questions on the 70 weeks already.

This website is for Judaism

Basically, any attempt to apply Daniel 9 to Jesus, is erroneous, and fraught with mistranslations and misinterpretations.
Note, that there are 27 books in the Greek Testament, and NONE of them quote Daniel 9!
Not any of the authors of Matthew, Mark, Luke, or John. Not in the letters of Paul. Not in the letters of Peter.
Apparently, no one in first century Christianity thought that it was important enough to mention an alleged prophecy about the exact year their Messiah was going to get killed. This implies, that even in the early years of POST Jesus, Daniel 9 was still not interpreted as being about Jesus.

Why can't it be a chiddush?

@ClintEastwood The Xtians believe that their Greek Testament, is the inspired word of God (2 Timothy 3:16). So, if God didn't include it in His alleged messages via the gospels, Paul, and Peter, then it's not from God. That's my response to the Xtians who invoke Daniel 9. However, the fact is that Jesus never fulfilled the basic Messianic prophecies, so Daniel couldn't possibly have been referring to him.

To which the Christian would say that we claim our Torah/Tanach is the inspired word of God and we have chiddushim that aren't inside it.
